# How to highlight heading in python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am able to highlight a run like this:

```
p = self.document.add_paragraph(style="List Bullet")
run = p.add_run(articles_date[i] + ": ")
run.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW
```

But how do I highlight a heading. This gives error:

```
h = self.document.add_heading(country + " " + sourcetype, level=3)
h.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 111, in <module>
    main("." ,"data", "templates", "combined.docx",document = "1", new_data=json_data)
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 47, in main
    document_one.exec()
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\DocumentOne.py", line 119, in exec
    self.create_section_two()
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\DocumentOne.py", line 80, in create_section_two
    h = self.document.add_heading.add_run(country + " " + sourcetype, level=3)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'add_run'
```

Edit:

I applied color like this

```
h = self.document.add_heading(country + " " + sourcetype, level=3)
h.style.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW
```

But it's not working :/

Tried this test code:

```
doc = docx.Document()
doc.add_paragraph("joiiii")
heading = doc.add_heading("hellow")
heading.style.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW
heading2  = doc.add_heading("new heading")

doc.add_paragraph("joiiii")
doc.save("test.docx")
```

It highlights even the one not needed to be highlighted

Comment: The immediate cause of your error message is that you are expected to do `self.document.add_heading().add_run(...)`.

Comment: I tried the other one

Answer (score 1):

Highlight is applied at the run level (as is all character formatting) and a heading is a paragraph. So you need something like this:

```
heading = document.add_heading("my heading")
for run in heading.runs:
    run.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW
```